# How to add a class on React component mount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My React app has a base div like so:

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        ....
    </div>
</body>
```

In my Welcome container, I would like to add a class to the div w id="root and then on Welcome container unmount, remove the class.

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    console.log($('#root'));
  }
  ....
```

With jQuery I could do something like

```
$('#root').addClass('myClass')
....
$('#root').removeClass('myClass')
```

What is the equivalent in React for adding and removing a class on a div after finding it by its ID?

Comment: Can I ask why? React isn't meant to work seamlessly with jQuery because it can violate React's lifecycle and convention.

Comment: I'm not trying to use jQuery, I'm looking for the React way of doing something in jQuery.

Comment: Oh whoops, sorry. You could definitely find the DOM node and add a class but I don't think that would be a good idea. What's the underlying problem?

Comment: Why is adding `class` special? I think you are asking how to set a property to a parent in React. I don't think you should look for "jQuery way" to do things in React, they are fundamentally different. I don't think you should use `id` attributes in any way while using react. Apart from that, `root` is just an HTML element, you can simply add/remove classes as you do with any HTML element.

Comment: You could simply have a `rootClass` property in your `store` state if you use `redux`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This makes no sense. You shouldn't be adding classes to root from React components. The root div should just exist to inject React in to using ReactDOM.

Instead of modifying the html root, create a react class called `App` or something and render a `<div className="app" />` that wraps all of your components. You can then use React state or props to modify the className.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            appClass: 'myClass'
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ appClass: 'newClass' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.state.appClass}>
                // Render children here
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

If you want to modify the `appClass` from a child component such as `Welcome` which is further down in your application then you will need to use a state management like Redux or Flux to modify the className from a child component otherwise it will get messy fast.

EDIT: removed semicolon from this.state object